# Acer aspire battey pin diagram

Tags: voltage, soldering

I have an Acer Aspire laptop and it has a 6 cell Ar4920LR laptop battery, I need to figure out what two pins are used for charging the laptop battery.  Can anyone take the battery out of anyone and plug it in to test the voltage of the battery pins?

Comment: do you have access to a multimeter ? Messing about with battery pins without one sounds kinda, exciting.

Comment: Here’s [a couple](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_repair_a_laptop_battery) [of pages](http://www.g-batteryshop.com/blogs/How-to-service-laptop-batteries.htm) that have pinouts for standard SMBus batteries.

Comment: Yes, I do have a meter, but the charging circuit needs to be repaired, I need a quick temporary fix till then.

Comment: Synetech, your links were really helpful, now I need to know what voltage the laptop outputs to the battery if someone could test that (two far outer pins) it would be all I believe that I need.  If the laptop were working I could test that myself.